# How can I get this sorted by descending order? (when the number and character is used together)

Tags: shell, sh

`files | sort -u | cut -f 3 > chr.list`

I got the results here and I would like to get this by number in descending order like chr1 chr2 chr3 ...  [image: Screenshot]

How can I solve this?

I thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Use the reverse switch in sort - `sort -ru`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
sort -t r -k 2 -g
```

where "r" is the last string not numeric

PS: `sort -V` should work too